# How to easily make ionic tabs navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

As I recently started working with "ionic", I am facing a problem making a "tabs navigation".

I was following a simple tutorial, I made a navigation with two tabs, but I couldn't make three tabs, it doesn't work properly, I'm afraid I didn't understand the concept of these tabs.

[CODEPEN CODE + DEMO](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/MwjGPY)

Here is my awesome code :

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-dark tabs-color-energized">

        <ion-tab title="help"ui-sref="help">
           <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="home" ui-sref="home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view> 
        </ion-tab>

     <ion-tab title="contact" ui-sref="contact">
            <ion-nav-view name="contact"></ion-nav-view> 
        </ion-tab>



    </ion-tabs> 
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content padding="true">
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <p>Here's the main route for the app.</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="help.html">
  <ion-view title="Help">
    <ion-content padding="true">
       <h2>Using the app</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis architecto hic officia quasi excepturi sequi deleniti maiores consectetur veritatis sint?</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="contact.html">
  <ion-view title="Contact">
    <ion-content padding="true">
       <h2>Using the app</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis architecto hic officia quasi excepturi sequi deleniti maiores consectetur veritatis sint?</p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

app.js :

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  views: {
    home: {
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    }
  }
})

 .state('help', {
  url: '/help',
  views: {
    help: {
      templateUrl: 'help.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('contact', {
  url: '/contact',
  views: {
    help: {
      templateUrl: 'contact.html'
    }
  }
})


})
```

http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/MwjGPY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views at your `contact` state you still have `help` as a view:

```
.state('contact', {
    url: '/contact',
        views: {
            help: { // <-- Change this to 'contact'
                templateUrl: 'contact.html'
            }
        }
})
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwzyB)

Comment: Do you know please how to make a default launch tab ?? in my case is "help" tab how to change for example to "home" tab ?

Comment: Yes, include this in your `.config` block: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');`

Comment: yeah I did but this is not working you can check the codepen you made !

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain you how that work.

So in your app.js file you have the configuration of routing. This routing will allow you to associate a state at an url and a template (file.html).
ref: [Ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

In your html page : 
This directive ui-sref="help" will call the state "help" and display a page (templateUrl). In this case this will display the content of help.html

```
    <ion-tab title="help"ui-sref="help">
       <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

In this exemple every html pages are in the main html page : Exemple : this is the help.html page

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="help.html">
       <ion-view title="Help">
         <ion-content padding="true">
          <h2>Using the app</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis architecto hic officia quasi excepturi sequi deleniti maiores consectetur veritatis sint?</p>
            </ion-content>
       </ion-view>
     </script>
```

There you have one mistake :

```
 .state('contact', {
  url: '/contact',
   views: {
      contact: { // here it's not help but contact
       templateUrl: 'contact.html'
     }
    }
 })
```

I hope this help you, sorry if my english is not correct. This tutorial can help you : [Ionic routing tutorial](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/)

Comment: Nice grabbing from my answer :)